# How does std::setw work with string output?

Tags: c++, string, setw

I am trying to use set width `setw` for string output to an output file, however, I am not able to make it work. I have with me the following example.

```
// setw example
#include <iostream>     
#include <iomanip>      
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    std::ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open("file.txt");
    output_file << "first" <<std::setw(5)<< "second"<< std::endl;
    output_file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** 
 With the above lines I expected to have many spaces between `first` and `second`, something like
`first                  second`

I hardly see any spaces, the output just comes like `firstsecond`
I think I missed the working of `setw()`

**Note:** For integers, it works fine just:

```
output_file << 1 <<std::setw(5)<< 2 << std::endl;
```

What I am doing wrong??.

Comment: Try using it on a string *smaller* than five characters (`"second"` is six characters long). Note that `...<< setw(5) << 123456 <<...` would not "work" either.

Comment: "I am not able to make it work." - Perhaps your question would make more sense if we all knew (a) what your definition of "work" is, and (b) what is actually happening and how it differs from (a). Are you hoping for some sort of *truncation* in the output? If so, your question should state that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks!! If i need a space between `first` and `second` why it need to be `six chars long `, so Its not much about space.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, actually I don't get any spaces between `first` and `second`.

Comment: Let me put it differently: Put examples of what you are *hoping to get*, and what you're *actually getting*, for output *in your question*. I suspect the problem is you simply don't understand how the [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) manipulator functions.

Comment: @WhozCraig Kindly find the edit above.

Comment: Edit shows you just need more space, why not to use `\t` or `\t\t` or `\t\t\t`.

Comment: the width of `2` is obviously less than 5, whereas `second` is not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect your understanding of `std::setw` is simply not correct. I think you need something more along the lines of a combination of:

- [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for setting field width
- [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) for setting the fill character
- [`std::left`, `std::right`, `std::internal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) for setting the write position *within the specified field width*.

What is happening in your code:

- Uses `std::setw(5)` to establish a field width of five characters.
- Sends `"first"` to the stream, which is five characters long, so the established field width is completely consumed. No additional filling takes place.
- Sends `"second"` to the stream, which is six characters long, so again, the entire field width is consumed (and in-fact breached). Again, no filling takes place

If you're intent is to have something like this (with column numbers above to show positions):

```
 col: 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
      first     second    third     fourth
```

Notice how each word starts on an even multiple of 10 boundary. One way to do that is by using :

- A output position `std::left` (so the fill, if any goes on the *right* to achieve the desired width).  This the default for strings, but it never hurts to be sure.
- A fill character of `std::setfill(' ')`. Again, the default.
- A field width `std::setw(10)` Why such a large number? See below

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setfill(' ')
              << std::setw(10) << "first"
              << std::setw(10) << "second"
              << std::setw(10) << "third"
              << std::setw(10) << "fourth" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (column numbers added)

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
first     second    third     fourth
```

---

So what happens if we change the output location to `std::right` ? Well, with the identical program, changing only the first line to :

```
std::cout << std::right << std::setfill(' ')
```

we get

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     first    second     third    fourth
```

---

Finally, one constructive way of seeing where the fill characters are being applied is by simply changing the fill char to something visible (ie. something besides a space). The last two examples output, changing the fill char to `std::setfill('*')` produces the following output:

First

```
first*****second****third*****fourth****
```

Second

```
*****first****second*****third****fourth
```

Notice in both cases, since none of the individual output items breached the `std::setw` value, the *total* output line size for each is the same. All that changed was where the fills were applied and the output aligned within the `std::setw` specification.

Comment: WhozCraig thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help me understand some of the more inconsistent behaviour of C++ std::setw 's I ask about here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824962/how-to-understand-c-stdsetw-s-inconsistent-behaviour